# Support for USB in chrome

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome, jakarta-ee, applet

I have a web application which will copy files from server to an end user usb. The end user will plugin USB to their machine and application will copy the files to user's usb. It was working with applet and now my application stopped working because chrome stopped supporting applet. Is there any way I can port this to chrome?

I read about node usb.
https://github.com/nonolith/node-usb

This requires the usb to be plugged into the same machine where node is running. My case is different because user will plugin usb in their machine only.

Another option was java web start which is not working. Can we get any plugin for chrome to support NAPI? Any ways to achieve this?

Any helps will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You should *probably* start here: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_usb. Be warned though, you'll be fighting an uphill battle.

Comment: Why was java webstart not working? It's generally one of the easiest way to keep an applet running though outside the browser then.

Comment: Java web start cannot interact with the browser, we have requirement to show some screen and validation message to the user also it is not sharing the same authentication of browser. It is running as a separate entity. Also If we try to run applet using webstart still browser should support NAPI.